# mvc set model value from javascript before submitting is null

Tags: jquery, html, ajax, model-view-controller

I am doing an MVC 5 Application. I have a `Ajax.BeginForm`.

View when I call a Function to make same validation before submit.

```csharp
@using (Ajax.BeginForm("Method", "Controller", ajaxOpts))
{
}

@{
    AjaxOptions ajaxOpts = new AjaxOptions
    {
        InsertionMode = InsertionMode.Replace,
        HttpMethod = "POST",
        OnSuccess = "processResponse",
        OnBegin = "StartValidation"
    };
}
```

I have `Hidden` Field for some Models Properties.
On `StartValidation` function I assign some values to those Property.

```csharp
@Html.HiddenFor(model => model.Prop1, new { @id = "Prop1" })
@Html.HiddenFor(model => model.Prop2, new { @id = "Prop2" })
```

```js
function StartValidation() {
  $('#Prop1').val(13);
  $('#Prop2').val(123);
  alert($('#Prop1').val());
  return true;
}
```

When I submit the View and Validation function is called, the value 123 is assign to Prop1 Hidden Field.

But, on server side `Method` of the `Controller`, the Prop1 and Prop2 are nulls..

On server side looks like this

```html
 [HttpPost]
        [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
        public async Task<ActionResult> Save(AlertView model)
        {
        }
```

Where `model.Prop1` and `model.Prop2` are nulls.

I believe the problem is that i can not assign value before Submit. If I assign value via JavaScript function under others circumstances, for instance, `onclick event`. On server side it gets the value of both properties.

What is wrong?

Comment: What is the Post value?

Comment: The server side post `method` model should contain that properties prop1 and prop2. And also it should be integer datatype.

Comment: put your server side code . then we can give right suggestion for you.